# Drawing a line betwen two nodes which are in separate images

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to draw a line between two circles in the below code?

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 

\tikzset{
    crcl/.style={draw, thick, shape=circle }
}

\newcommand*{\MyPic}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw #1 rectangle #2;
        \node[crcl] at #1 (c) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=blue] at (0,0) (a) {\MyPic{(0,0)}{(1,1)}}; 
    \node[fill=green] [xshift=2cm] at (0,0) (b) {\MyPic{(0,0)}{(1,1)}}; 
    \draw[thick] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works with the `remember picture` key and distinctive node names.

This needs at least two compilations.

As an extra, I redefined `\MyPic` in a more TikZ-way:

```
\MyPic (<p1>) (<p2>) {<name>}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    crcl/.style={draw, thick, shape=circle }
}

\newcommand*{\MyPic}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \draw #1 rectangle #2;
        \node[crcl] at #1 (c#3) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\def\MyPic(#1)#2(#3)#4{% remove this if new syntax is not wanted
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture] %
        \draw (#1) rectangle (#3);        %
        \node[crcl] at (#1) (c#4) {};     %
    \end{tikzpicture}%                    %
}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \node[fill=blue]              at (0,0) (a) {\MyPic (0,0) (1,1) {a}}; 
    \node[fill=green, xshift=2cm] at (0,0) (b) {\MyPic (0,0) (1,1) {b}}; 
    \draw[thick]                           (ca) -- (cb);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Any reason not to just use `\tikzmark` which sort of packages this kind of solution?

Comment: @PeterGrill Now that you say it, I have tried it: The best I got was an `overlay`ed circle (the bounding box (blue/green) didn’t got updated). The `\subnode` command sounds promising, though the closest I got was `\subnode{salt-#3}{\node[crcl] at #1 (c#3) {};}` where I had to use again `(ca)` and `(cb)`. `salt-#3` gives only the center (`#1`). I want the node “marked” not the point.

Comment: Now that I look at it more carefully I guess you'd have to do a custom `\tikzmark` which places the node.